# How to separate different sound sources with FastICA on Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have to 2 wave files, from two different microphones, recorded during a interview.

I need to separate the voices, to find the two original sound sources: one file with the woman voice only, the other file with the man voice only.
(I want to have the same result presented here: http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/cocktail/cocktail_en.cgi).

I downloaded the **FastICA** package for Matlab on the same website: research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/code/dlcode.shtml

Here is my code to **separate the two voices**, and finally get **two wave files**.

```
% Extract wave files
[Y, FS, BPS] = wavread('input_A.wav');
[Z, FS, BPS] = wavread('input_B.wav');

Y = Y';
Z = Z';

% Create the matrix with the two different channels
X = [Y; Z];

% Display the two input signals
figure('Name', 'Input Y Z');
subplot(2, 1, 1); plot(X(1, :));
subplot(2, 1, 2); plot(X(2, :));

% Run the algorithm
[S, A, W] = fastica(X);

% Display the two output signals
figure('Name', 'Sources');
subplot(2, 1, 1); plot(S(1, :));
subplot(2, 1, 2); plot(S(2, :));

% Extract the two sources
Y = S(1, :);
Z = S(2, :);

% Write wave files
wavwrite(Y, FS, BPS, 'output_1.wav');
wavwrite(Z, FS, BPS, 'output_2.wav');
```

Here is the output of the algorithm:

```
> Number of signals: 2.
> Number of samples: 480000.
> Calculating covariance...
> Dimension not reduced.
> Selected [ 2 ] dimensions.
> Smallest remaining (non-zero) eigenvalue [ 0.000693973 ].
> Largest remaining (non-zero) eigenvalue [ 0.00107027 ].
> Sum of removed eigenvalues [ 0 ].
> [ 100 ] % of (non-zero) eigenvalues retained.
> Whitening...
> Check: covariance differs from identity by [ 8.88178e-16 ].
> Used approach [ defl ].
> Used nonlinearity [ pow3 ].
> Warning: Data vectors are very long. Plotting may take long time.
> Starting ICA calculation...
> IC 1 .....computed ( 5 steps ).
> IC 2 ..computed ( 2 steps ).
> Done.
> Adding the mean back to the data.
```

[Here](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/140765inputoutput.png) are the signals displayed:

[image]

I really don't understand why the output signals are almost the same as the input signals on those figures ? **Why the voices are not separated ?**

Thanks in advance to anyone who reads this post and try to answer it !

Comment: I guess because ICA is a magical tool that only works in the hands of an ICA specialist. ;-) That's my impression anyway. If you don't get an answer here, ask to get the question moved to dsp.SE.

Comment: Did you try the examples on the ics.aalto website, just to make sure your code is correct? Can you upload your mixed wav files?